# Insufficient fund

Tags: ether, sepolia

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox');

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const API_KEY=process.env.API_KEY

console.log("API_URL:", API_URL);
console.log("PRIVATE_KEY:", PRIVATE_KEY);
console.log("API_KEY:", API_KEY);
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      gasPrice: 9500000000 // 1 gwei
    },
```

},
};

I am building an nft app, and for minting, each costs around **0.02eth**. I am deploying on Sepolia, which currently has 1 ETH on Sepolia. What the issue is whenever I try to deploy, I get this error:

```
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost',
  code: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS',
  error: ProviderError: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
      at HttpProvider.request (/home/athul/NFT/node_modules/hardh
```

Comment: It's clear, 0.02eth is not enough to pay for gas of the operation you are trying to perform

Comment: Can you share your config file's content?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma shared now

Comment: @ATHULSURESH Are you using the correct Private Key?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes it is correct. i try to deploy it on goerli and having same error [diffrent private kay and url ] though

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to use the overrides passing gasLimit and gasPrice.

```
myContract.mint(myParam, {gasPrice:1.5* current gasPrice at sepholia, gasLimit: YOUR GAS LIMIT}
```

Hope it helps